# VBA: Replacing space bars with blank spaces?

Tags: vba, excel

I am running a code that pulls data from PI using conditional formula. When the values are pulled, it assigns the formula to entire column but only few of them have actual values:

[image]

The column has about 300,000 rows but I want to run the loop only when I have actual values (4 times instead of 300,000 in this case).

Are there any suggestions to do it avoiding the loop 300,000 times?

I have tried using the replace function by replacing all the spaces with blank and then count the number of non-blank cells using `COUNTA` :

```
'Replacing all spaces in a column by blanks
Workseets("Sheet6").Range("D:D") = Replace(Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("D:D")," ","")
'counting non-blank cells
n = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("D:D"))
'running code only 4 times
for I = 1 to n.....
```

But I am getting type mismatch error for the replace function. I have not written anything inside for `FOR Loop` yet. Currently just trying to use the `REPLACE` function correctly

Comment: `Dim n As Long` and `Dim I as Long`, 300,000 well exceeds the limit of integer data type. Also, please consider showing what you're doing inside the loop.

Comment: If a loop is necessary (and it may not be) you could use `Do While` loop instead of `For` loop, with criteria to exit when the cell value is empty.

Comment: Ideally, instead of using hard-coded `Workseets("Sheet6").Range("D:D")` you'll define a proper Range variable that represents only the rows/data you want to process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt uses the `String.Replace` function and causes a mismatch error, because you're passing a variant/range to a function which expects a string.

```
'Replacing all spaces in a column by blanks
Workseets("Sheet6").Range("D:D") = Replace(Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("D:D")," ","")
```

A solution is to use the `Range.Replace` method, instead. No assignment is necessary, the method operates on the range object which calls it. This copies the values directly and replaces the empty string

```
'Replacing all spaces in a column by blanks
 With Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("D:D")
    .Value = .Value2
    .Replace " ", "", xlWhole
 End With
```

Comment: Range.Replace only returns a Boolean function. It is giving TRUE for every cell in the column

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `Intersect` method to trim the range down to the actual used cells.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet6")

    Intersect(.Range("D:D"), .UsedRange).Replace " ", ""

End With
```

Comment: If the range has spaces or other non-printing characters, or contains formula which output same, the UsedRange will not be reliable. (There are other reasons why UsedRange is not always reliable, too!)

Comment: From the OP there: *it assigns the formula to entire column but only few of them have actual values*.

Comment: Rather than get in a pissing match about this, it would've been much more appropriate for you to simply *edit* my answer for what is an obvious oversight.